# factorygirl create error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

When I was debugging in console with pry,I have run brief =  Factory(:brief,:project => Factory(:project)) this command.It supposed to be work but I got this error.

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_briefs_on_project_id"
    DETAIL:  Key (project_id)=(15389) already exists.
    : INSERT INTO "briefs" ("project_id", "duration", "brand_name", "brand_info", 
"customer_info", "competitor_info", "desired_impression", "competencies", "preferences",
 "examples", "notes", "created_at", "updated_at", "channel_id") VALUES (15389, 14, NULL, 
'brand info', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
'2013-04-06 01:07:04.717364', '2013-04-06 01:07:04.717364', NULL) RETURNING "id"
```

Why this error occurs and how can I fix it ?

Edited: I added my factory files

**brief_factory.rb**

```
Factory.define :brief, :class => Brief do |b|
  b.brand_info 'brand info'
  b.duration 14
end
```

**project_factory.rb**

```
Factory.define :project, :class => Project do |p|
  p.association :owner, :factory => :customer

  p.title 'project title'
  p.description 'project description'
  p.stage :brief_completed
  p.contest_type :standard

  p.brief Factory.build(:brief)
  p.association :project_type, :factory => :project_type
end
```

Comment: Please add your factory definition code to the question.

Comment: I added factory files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `project` factory is automatically creating `brief`. So `Factory(:brief,:project => Factory(:project))` will attempt to create two briefs associated with the same project. The second fails because you have a unique constraint on the `project_id` column in the `briefs` table.

With the factories that you have defined you can probably do what you are trying to do in Pry with:

```
project = Factory(:project)
brief = project.brief
```

or just:

```
brief = Factory(:project).brief
```